# mysql how i can get all data past in date Now -1 month

Tags: mysql, sql

i have data in mysql ex nom : date
how i can get noms in date Now -1 month
just data in past without last month

ex data
john : 2022/03/17
john : 2022/04/17
john : 2022/01/17
john : 2021/03/17
john : 2021/04/17
john : 2021/02/17

i want for exemple

john : 2022/01/17
john : 2021/03/17
john : 2021/04/17
john : 2021/02/17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't completely understand your question but this might be helpful.

You can filter your data by using `WHERE` clause to get the records where date is less than today's date - 1 month. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE date < (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```